# Adding a second Y-axis using axlsx gem

Tags: ruby, charts, axlsx

Is there a way to add a second Y-axis to a line chart using the axlsx gem. I currently have two data sets (data-series) and one set is much larger than the other. Does anyone have experience using SerAxis or adding a second Y-axis?

Comment: For future visitors: there is a [deleted link-only answer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/14474321) by the OP. Apparently this is solved [here](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/pull/431/commits/6057277d7a8473121ba63983913bd91d1e4c0a9b).